# Uncrustify for c++ adds closed parenthesis after comma templated parameters

Tags: c++, uncrustify

I have the following function:

```
template<typename Gender, typename Age> bool checkSomething( param1, param2, param3)
{...}
```

when I put the following function call through Uncrustify:

```
if( somethingChanged == checkSomething<Female, OverThirty>( param1, param2, param3)) 
{...}
```

it changes it to

```
if( somethingChanged == checkSomething<Female) , OverThirty>( param1, param2, param3)) 
{...}
```

Notice the extra closed parenthesis after Female

This obviously breaks my code. I would appreciate any ideas about how to turn it off.

Comment: ?perhaps the [Yoda Condition](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html) confusing is

Comment: It appears to be puking on the template-param-list specifier. I.e. It thinks `checkSomething<Female` is saying "test checkSomething is less than female". Lovely piece of workmanship on that little gem, and I've *no* idea how to turn it off (apart from the blatantly obvious answer: don't use it).

Comment: Changes nothing the yoda condition. I've already tried.
PS: However, the parentheses switched sides! That's definitely a clue. Thank you, Bo

Comment: The problem with "don't use it" is that it all throughout the code, and is actually very useful and easy to read, write and understand (when you see it in its entirety.

Comment: @BoPersson, changing the yoda condition, changed the parenthesis side which indicated that it's a condition connected to if statement parenthesis. mod_full_paren_if_bool = false solved my problem. Thanks again